# Extracting data from embedded python using Boost::Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, segmentation-fault, boost-python

I'm trying to learn a little of boost::python, and I'm stuck on extracting data from a python string.

Currently, I am able to compile cleanly, but when executing the code, I receive a segmentation fault.  I've narrowed the seg-fault down to the line which actually uses boost::python::extract.

I'm hoping for guidance.  Thanks in advance!

For convenience, I have provided a github repo:  https://github.com/brianbruggeman/boost_python_hello_world/tree/feature/stack_overflow

Cpp Code (say_hello.cpp):

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bp = boost::python;

// Embedding python
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int data = 0;
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("data = 1");
    bp::object module(bp::handle<>(bp::borrowed(PyImport_AddModule("__main__"))));
    bp::object dictionary = module.attr("__dict__");
    bp::object data_obj = dictionary["data"];
    // Error: The following line has the segmentation fault...
    data = bp::extract<int>(data_obj);
    std::cout << "data = " << data << std::endl;
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  For completeness, I'm using Mac OS X Mavericks and I'm including the CMakeLists.txt file below:

```
project(hello)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS python)

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUD_DIRS})
link_directories(${PYTHON_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(hello say_hello.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Python was compiled and installed using Homebrew:

```
brew install python
```

Boost was compiled and installed using Homebrew:

```
brew install boost --with-python
```

Edit (new installation for boost-python):

```
brew install --build-from-source boost-python
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine.  The build process is the problem.

Brew is buildling the `libboost_python` library against the python libraries installed from Brew's python package:

```
$ otool -L $(brew list boost | grep "libboost_python.dylib")
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0_2/lib/libboost_python.dylib:
    /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib (...)
    /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (...) <-- brew
    ...
```

However, CMake is linking against the OSX system provided Python library:

```
$ (mkdir build && cd build && cmake ../)
...
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (found version "2.7.5") 
...
```

Thus, the program and Boost.Python are linked against different Python libraries, resulting in undefined behavior.  To resolve this, either fix the `FindPythonLibs.cmake` file or update `CMakeLists.txt` to explicitly link against the brew provided Python library.

---

Here is a complete `CMakeLists.txt` example that explicitly sets the `PYTHON_LIBRARIES` variable to the Python library installed by brew on my system:

```
project(hello)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(PythonLibs)
set(PYTHON_LIBRARIES /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python)

include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(hello say_hello.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

And its usage:

```
$ (mkdir build && cd build && cmake ../ && make)
...
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (found version "2.7.5") 
...
Scanning dependencies of target hello
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/say_hello.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable hello
[100%] Built target hello
$ ./build/hello
data = 1
```

Note that PythonLibs will still print the library it found, but the `PYTHON_LIBRARIES` variable was explicitly set to the appropriate library.

---

A few other things to note:

- Boost.Python does not support safely calling [`Py_Finalize()`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#Py_Finalize).  Per the [Embedding - Getting started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/embedding.html) section:

  > Note that at this time you must not call `Py_Finalize()` to stop the interpreter. This may be fixed in a future version of boost.python.
- When embedding, I often find it helpful to use a `try/catch` block, catching the [`boost::python::error_already_set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/errors.html) exception and printing errors:

  ```cpp
  Py_Initialize();
  try
  {
    // ...
  }
  catch (boost::python::error_already_set&)
  {
    PyErr_Print();
  }
  ```

Comment: Today, boost-python should be installed with:

brew install --build-from-source boost-python